# How to remove links on my account navigation?

Tags: customer-account, navigation, magento1.9.2.4

i wanted to remove "billing agreement" "recurring profile" "customer token" "My Downloadable Products" in account navigation.

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

please help me .

Comment: Refer my answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50234/remove-customer-account-dashboard-links

Comment: Disable module like catalog downloadable for disable my downloadable products

Answer (score 2):

Billing Agreements : 
copy this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml`
in your current theme and remove below lines

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
    <action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>billing_agreements</name><path>sales/billing_agreement/</path><label>Billing Agreements</label></action>
</reference>
```

Recurring Profiles : 
copy this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml`
in your current theme and remove below lines

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
        <action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>recurring_profiles</name><path>sales/recurring_profile/</path><label>Recurring Profiles</label></action>
    </reference>
```

My Downloadable Products : 
copy this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/downloadable.xml`
in your current theme and remove below lines

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using following code in your theme local.xml

```
<customer_account>
         <reference name="left">
            <!--Remove the whole block -->
            <action
method="unsetChild"><name>customer_account_navigation</name></action>
            <!-- if you don't want to add any link just skip below part -->
            <block type="customer/account_navigation"
name="customer_account_navigation" before="-"
template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label"
module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account
Dashboard</label></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Using the above code in your local.xml file will remove the links to your account navigation.